# How to get show.gsp param and pass it to another controller

Tags: redirect, grails, gsp, grails-3.3

I am try to do something like this
[Get(param.id) in Controller.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238747/grails-domain-getparams-id-works-in-controller-show-but-not-contoller-edit)
and forward/redirect(I am not sure) to another controller.

Here's the question, how can I manage to capture the selected (show.gsp)'s param (example:taskName), and "send" it out to another controller.

**EDIT 1**

I had figure out how to capture

```css
def taskName = Task.get(params.id)
```

May I know how to "send" out "taskName"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried with redirect or forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following should work for you,

```
     def show(){
                 def taskName = Task.get(params.id)
                //Using redirect
                 redirect(controller: "AnotherController", action: "ActionInAnotherController", params: [taskName:taskName])

                //OR using forward

                def model = [
                    taskName : taskNme, 
                ]

                forward(controller:"AnotherController",action:"ActionInAnotherController", model:model)

                //OR using chain
                chain(controller:'AnotherController',action:'ActionInAnotherController ',model:model)

             //Redirect to another domain controller
               redirect(url: "anotherDomainUrl/AnotherController/ActionInAnotherController", params: [taskName:taskName])

 }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you quick reply. I would like to know more about redirect.
When I do redirect, issit ok to redirect to another domain's controller? If yes, how should i define?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Trainee I have updated my answer, provided a way for another domain